# Trying to reconcile 2 tables. One has duplicates and the other does not

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables I am trying to reconcile using SQL.

The first table has multiple instances of some records. 
The second table only has one instance of each record.

I don't want to delete any duplicates out of the first table.

I need to know which records in the first table do not have any matches in the second table. What I have done so far keeps giving me the duplicate records as non-matching since one instance has already been matched. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left outer join` from the first table to the second and in your `WHERE` clause look for records where the second table join column(s) `IS NULL`.